# MockRestServiceServer.verify() is failed when the test did not mock all of API in the project

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-test, mockrestserviceserver

My project have 2 APIs and I want to separate test for each API.
So I am trying to use MockRestServiceServer to mock my API but MockRestServiceServer requires all of API that I have in my project have to mock even it does not need.

My spring boot version:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

There are my code: using 2 schedules to call 2 APIs

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000)
public void schedule1() {
    restTemplate.getForEntity(URI.create("http://localhost:9090/api1"), String.class);
}
    
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000)
public void schedule2() {
    restTemplate.getForEntity(URI.create("http://localhost:9090/api2"), String.class);
}
```

And my test

```
@Test
void testSchedule1() {
    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).ignoreExpectOrder(true).build();
    mockServer
        .expect(ExpectedCount.manyTimes(),
            MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(new StringStartsWith("http://localhost:9090/api1")))
        .andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.method(HttpMethod.GET))
        .andRespond(MockRestResponseCreators.withStatus(HttpStatus.OK).body(""));

    mockServer.verify(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
}
    
@Test
void testSchedule2() {
    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).ignoreExpectOrder(true).build();
    mockServer
        .expect(ExpectedCount.manyTimes(),
            MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(new StringStartsWith("http://localhost:9090/api2")))
        .andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.method(HttpMethod.GET))
        .andRespond(MockRestResponseCreators.withStatus(HttpStatus.OK).body(""));

    mockServer.verify(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
}
```

As default, 2 schedules will run in the same thread. So schedule1 executed first, then the testSchedule1 passed and testSchedule2 always failed.

```
2022-04-02 21:50:30.374 ERROR 2284 --- \[   scheduling-1\] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task

org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:9090/api1": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785) \~\[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:751) \~\[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:377) \~\[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
at com.example.demo1.test.Test.schedule1(Test.java:18) \~\[classes/:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) \~\[na:na\]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) \~\[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) \~\[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) \~\[na:na\]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:498) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:603) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.\<init\>(HttpClient.java:246) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:351) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:373) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1309) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1057) \~\[na:na\]
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76) \~\[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) \~\[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) \~\[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776) \~\[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
... 15 common frames omitted

2022-04-02 21:50:30.376 ERROR 2284 --- \[   scheduling-1\] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task

org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:9090/api2": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785) \~\[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:751) \~\[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:377) \~\[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
at com.example.demo1.test.Test.schedule2(Test.java:23) \~\[classes/:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) \~\[na:na\]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) \~\[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) \~\[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) \~\[na:na\]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:498) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:603) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.\<init\>(HttpClient.java:246) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:351) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:373) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1309) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1057) \~\[na:na\]
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76) \~\[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) \~\[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) \~\[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776) \~\[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18\]
... 15 common frames omitted

2022-04-02 21:50:33.392 ERROR 2284 --- \[   scheduling-1\] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task

java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP GET http://localhost:9090/api1
0 request(s) executed.

    at org.springframework.test.web.client.AbstractRequestExpectationManager.createUnexpectedRequestError(AbstractRequestExpectationManager.java:213) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.test.web.client.UnorderedRequestExpectationManager.matchRequest(UnorderedRequestExpectationManager.java:44) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.test.web.client.AbstractRequestExpectationManager.validateRequest(AbstractRequestExpectationManager.java:97) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer$MockClientHttpRequestFactory$1.executeInternal(MockRestServiceServer.java:338) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.mock.http.client.MockClientHttpRequest.execute(MockClientHttpRequest.java:110) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:751) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:377) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at com.example.demo1.test.Test.schedule1(Test.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

After checked, I recognized If any schedule run first, the test case of that schedule will be passed.
I have checked the source code of MockRestServiceServer. It comes to AbstractRequestExpectationManager
in the verify method will call verifyInternal()

```
private int verifyInternal() {
    if (this.expectations.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (!this.requestFailures.isEmpty()) {
        throw new AssertionError("Some requests did not execute successfully.\n" +
                this.requestFailures.entrySet().stream()
                    .map(entry -> "Failed request:\n" + entry.getKey() + "\n" + entry.getValue())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n", "\n", "")));
     }
     int count = 0;
     for (RequestExpectation expectation : this.expectations) {
         if (!expectation.isSatisfied()) {
             count++;
         }
     }
     return count;
}
```

And the **requestFailures** is the map stores all failed requests (expected and unexpected)

```
  @Override
  public ClientHttpResponse validateRequest(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
    RequestExpectation expectation;
    synchronized (this.requests) {
      if (this.requests.isEmpty()) {
        afterExpectationsDeclared();
      }
      try {
        // Try this first for backwards compatibility
        ClientHttpResponse response = validateRequestInternal(request);
        if (response != null) {
          return response;
        }
        else {
          expectation = matchRequest(request);
        }
      }
      catch (Throwable ex) {
        this.requestFailures.put(request, ex);
        throw ex;
      }
      finally {
        this.requests.add(request);
      }
    }
    return expectation.createResponse(request);
  }
```

If the schedule1 will be executed first, then it satisfied the condition: **if (this.expectations.isEmpty())** first and the test case will be passed.
If the schedule1 executed after schedule1, the **requestFailures** will store the error of API 1, then it satisfied this condition: **if (!this.requestFailures.isEmpty())** and the test case will be failed.

Is that MockRestServiceServer behavior? They want to mock all APIs?
If yes, please help me some alternative solution for my scenario.

Thanks